# bootstrap loginControl checkbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

i'm using bootstrap CSS for my application. I have `asp:login` control with "remember me" checkbox.
my problem is there is a space between checkbox and the word "remember me". i removed all checkbox css from my css files, but still couldn't fix the issue.
 I tried this css code to remove the white space

```
.chkbox{margin-left:0px;padding-left:0px;white-space:nowrap;}
```

and this is my Login control

```
<div class="contact-address span3" style="/*width:250px;*/margin-top:15px;padding-left:5px;">
   <h3 style="color:#1872AB;font-weight:normal;">LOGIN:</h3>                        
     <div class="login">
      <asp:Login ID="user_Login" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="user_Login_Authenticate" RememberMeText="Remember me" TitleText="" UserNameLabelText="Email:" PasswordLabelText="Password:" OnLoggedIn="SAP_Login_LoggedIn" >
      <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="con-tbutton"/>
      <CheckBoxStyle  CssClass="chkbox"/>
      </asp:Login>
      <table style="width:100%;">
      <tr><td style=""><label><a href="ResetPassword.aspx" style="color:#6a6a6a;">Forgot your password</a></label></td></tr>
      </table> 
   </div>
```

but still, it looks like the image below
[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the rendered HTML in your browsers Developer Tools? F12. It might be adding something that is causing to create a break. I hate asp controls, so I understand.

Comment: in developer tools I found this:
'data-twttr-rendered="true"'
in body tag

Comment: Hmm... don't think that has anything to do with this. I could be wrong. Did you try my solution in the Answer below?

Comment: yes, but still.
do you think it's because of ASP Login control or bootstrap CSS ??
but I already removed all checkbox CSS !!!
my experience with CSS is not that good!

Comment: I don't see you using any bootstrap CSS. I also don't see you using any Bootstrap classes. The CSS you have at the top, you don't need that. By default it will align the checkbox and label horizontally already. Sorry but I will need an html example to see what's going on. I would use jsbin.com and copy/paste the rendered HTML from F12. Then copy over the CSS too.

Comment: I just noticed that you're missing a closing `</div>` tag for your first div. Maybe that's the issue. Or did you just not copy it in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly made a sample aspx page, and it works just fine:

[image]

This is unstyled. As you see, the checkbox aligns just fine. I don't see any bootstrap styling in your example, or classes for that matter. It might be the closing `</div>` tag you're missing... This is the best I can give you without a live html example from you on [JS Bin](http://www.jsbin.com) or somewhere simlilar. Try what I suggested in my last comment.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions and help
JS Bin is a good site.
I discovered my issue, i have a CSS for my master page which affects all my pages.
removing all the css from master page makes it works. thanks again